# DirectX 12 D3DCompileFromFile doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, directx-12

I'm learning DirectX 12. I got an error at D3DCompileFromFile() function.

```cpp
    void Shader::CompileShader(const std::wstring& path, const std::string& name, const std::string& version, ID3DBlob* shaderBlob) {
#if defined(_DEBUG)
    // Enable better shader debugging with the graphics debugging tools.
    UINT compileFlags = D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#else
    UINT compileFlags = 0;
#endif

    ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile(path.c_str(), nullptr, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, name.c_str(), version.c_str(), compileFlags, 0, &shaderBlob, &mErrBlob));
}
```

mErrBlob said "Information not available, no symbols loaded for D3DCompiler_47.dll"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG5uh.png)

So I checked Microsoft Symbol Server option at Debug-Options-Debugging-Symbols. And then I got another error from mErrBlob which is "No type information available in symbol file for D3DCompiler_47.dll"

HRESULT value is E_FAIL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2rnJ.png)

I don't know anymore how to fix this error.

Comment: Your error blob contains text. print it.

Comment: @tkausl isn't it "No type information available in symbol file for D3DCompiler_47.dll"? I printed it using std::cout then it showed 000001FD90547050.

Comment: `isn't it "No type information available in symbol file for D3DCompiler_47.dll"` No, thats a error message from your debugger.  `I printed it using std::cout then it showed 000001FD90547050.` How? You're not supposed to _print the Blob itself_. Use `GetBufferPointer` and `GetBufferSize` to get its content.

Comment: @tkausl Really thank you. I got the address of mErrBlob, copied it and pasted it to memory. Then I found hex codes translated to string. Anyway, the reason that it didn't work is that I wrote wrong code to .hlsli file. REALLY THANK YOU.